# Flink drop processes that take too long, and commit checkpoint

Tags: apache-flink

I'm using Flink + Kafka to process streaming documents. I have set up filters on the documents to stop strange documents from coming into Flink jobs, but still there are types of documents that I couldn't foresee. If the job consumes these documents, it will take extra long time.

Like I have seen in the checkpoints of the job, many processes finish quite fast and are waiting for the slow ones to finish (e.g. in image below, all finished but one). My question is: can I make Flink drop these slow processes after certain threshold, and commit those that are already finished? I tried to set `flink.job.checkpoint.timeout` but found that the checkpoint will fail if it exceeds the timeout, and will read the last offset and process again. Is there a way to make the checkpoint succeed and read the next offset?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like this unaligned checkpoint is what I need. https://flink.apache.org/2020/10/15/from-aligned-to-unaligned-checkpoints-part-1.html

but have to upgrade flink to 1.11, and then set in flink-conf.yaml

```
execution.checkpointing.unaligned: true
execution.checkpointing.aligned-checkpoint-timeout: 60 s
```

Comment: FYI, unaligned checkpoints were experimental (and buggy) in 1.11. I would recommend 1.13 (or later) for the best experience.